# Network Policy doesn't work in play-with-k8s (kubernetes 1.7 + Weave Net)

Tags: kubernetes

I was [testing Network Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/declare-network-policy/) on [play-with-k8s](http://labs.play-with-k8s.com/), but it seems not working.
Network Policy has prerequisites:

1. Kubernets 1.7
2. Network plugin supports Network Policy

and play-with-k8s

1. is based on Kuberntes 1.7
2. need to install [Weave Net add-ons network plugin](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/), which [supports Network Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/weave-network-policy/)

But Network Policy has no effect in play-with-k8s. Any recommendations? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could test network policies by using minikube. Just make sure to set the `--network-plugin flag` when spinning up the cluster.